# Talkback not reading header's children views

Tags: android, accessibility, children, talkback

I add a header to a ListView. The header has several components (Buttons, TextViews, RelativeLayouts). When talkback is turned on, and the header is selected, the entirety of the header is read and you can't select individual components. Although, the buttons are selectable and talkback will read them. But the textviews are not separate.

How do I get the talkback to treat all the components in the header as individual components?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: You can't.

TalkBack is attempting to be smart, by collecting all of the infomative(read: not active) information within the list view cell (header views are still parts of the list view) and read it out as one element.  This associates any of the information within that cell together, I believe by marking the layout the objects are placed in as importantForAccessibility, though there may be some TalkBack magic happening using specific logic for ListView cells.

For example, if you had cells that looked like this:

```
Name: Chris
Address: Blah blah blah

Name: Herman
Address: Blarg blarg blarg
```

Each cell would read out:

```
Name: Chris Adress Blah Blah Blah
```

This is beneficial, as there are no ordering/data association issues.  What if the data were not wrapped together?  Does "Blah Blah Blah" address belong to Chris (the name before it), or Herman(the name after it)?  Active elements are ignored in this equation, because active elements need to be... well active.  And so must be individually focusable, so that a user may interact with them.

One could certainly argue the relative merits of this approach vs allowing the developer to make of the mistake of improper data association, but the decision has been made and you are stuck with it.

If you really care, you could re-invent the wheel, and create your own list view, using linear layouts, it's really not that hard.  In which case, you could of course get whatever behaviors you wish. OR, put your heading in a separate layout, rather than using the ListViews header cell.

Hypothetically, if my assumption about them using "isImportantForAccessibility" on the ListView cells is the way this is implemented (as opposed to some TalkBack magic for ListViews), you could crawl up the View Hierarchy to the Cell layout after it has been drawn (so the Android Framework has already had its way with it), and reset isImportantForAccessibility to no.  Though, I highly recommend against this approach as

A: I'm not sure it will work, this is just hypothetical(nope, not going to test it myself).  If the logic for this is indeed on the TalkBack side, you really and truly are hosed, unless you want to reinvent ListViews or write your own screen reader.

B: In general, these smart things that TalkBack tries to do help accessibility, and not hurt it.  Unless you really know accessibility, it is best to let Android do its thing.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I set the textviews to textIsSelectable(true), the Talkback recognizes those textviews as an element that can be selected. In order to not change the functionality of my app when the Talkback isn't activated, I used AccessibilityManager to check to see if Talkback was activated.